# jmeter groovy dynamic json request creation from csv

Tags: json, csv, groovy, jmeter

I need to create a JSON request dynamically starting from a csv file. 
The csv is formatted like this:

```
TEST_ID;TEST_DESC;RQ_FIELD1;RQ_FIELD2;RQ_FIELD3;RS_FIELD1;RS_FIELD2
TC1;TEST 1;input1;input2;input3;output1;output2
TC2;TEST 2;input1;;input3;output1;output2
TC3;TEST 3;input1;input2;missing;output1;output2
```

The request must be composed only by RQ_FIELDS* and:

If the field is empty the FIELD in the request must be left empty. 
If the field is equal to "missing" the FIELD should not be added to the request.

i.e.

```
TC1
    { "FIELD1": "input1",
      "FIELD2": "input2",
      "FIELD3": "input3"
    }
TC2
    { "FIELD1": "input1",
      "FIELD2": "",
      "FIELD3": "input3"
    }
TC3
    { "FIELD1": "input1",
      "FIELD2": "input2"
    }
```

I tried something, but I cannot create the request dynamically.

Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
def csv = '''TEST_ID;TEST_DESC;RQ_FIELD1;RQ_FIELD2;RQ_FIELD3;RS_FIELD1;RS_FIELD2 
TC1;TEST 1;input1;input2;input3;output1;output2 
TC2;TEST 2;input1;;input3;output1;output2 
TC3;TEST 3;input1;input2;missing;output1;output2​'''

def m = [:]
def rqIndexes = []
csv.eachLine{ aLine, cnt ->
    if ( cnt == 0 ) {
        rqIndexes = aLine.tokenize( ';' ).findIndexValues{ it.startsWith( 'RQ' ) }
    }
    else {
        def k
        aLine.split( ';' ).eachWithIndex{ token, idx ->
            if ( idx == 0 ) {
                k = token
                m.put( k, [:] )
            }
            else{
                if ( rqIndexes.contains( idx as Long ) && token != 'missing' ){
                    m.get( k ).put( "FIELD${idx-1}", token )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
groovy.json.JsonOutput.prettyPrint(groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson(m))​
```